# Storing ITextSharp Data

Tags: c#, .net, directory

So an update, I've gotten my code to be able to read a single pdf file and parse the information into a text file. Great. Now I want to figure out how to do the following two things.

1. Get the program to be able to read more than 1 pdf file. If I could get it to read an entire file folder, that would be best. I'm not sure how to change the code to do that, but I know it can't be that different.
2. Change the activation method. If I could get it so that the code ran whenever a new file was dropped into a folder, that would be absolutely amazing. That has to be possible, to somehow have an event listener that activates whenever a file is dropped into a folder and parses the information.

   ```
    public static string ExtractTextFromPdf(string path)
    {
        ITextExtractionStrategy its = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.LocationTextExtractionStrategy();

        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path))
        {
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

            for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {
                ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();

                string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, strategy);

                currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
                text.Append(currentText);
            }

            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\kttricic\OneDrive - Burns & McDonnell\Desktop\test file\POs\test");
            file.WriteLine(text);

            file.Close();

            return text.ToString();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ExtractTextFromPdf(@"C:\Users\kttricic\OneDrive - Burns & McDonnell\Desktop\test file\POs\PO 4505234816 Siemens Industry, Inc. 6.15.21.pdf"));
    }
   ```

Comment: I changed your tags as your issue is not the text extraction from PDF using iText but iterating over the files in a directory and watching directory contents in c# and .Net.